# Ionic App gives an error 500 when using proxy

Tags: javascript, json, proxy, ionic-framework

I have an embedded device that I want to connect to from my app through http. Therefore I have to use Ionic Proxy. So in my project file I have:

```
 {
  "name": "MyApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.0.100"
    }
  ]
}
```

But whenever my App (running in chrome) tries to get some JSON data from my embedded server, I get an error 500 even though it returns the correct JSON when I visit the API from my browser.

Here's the service I am using:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('device_status', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/device_status');
});
```

And when I try out the API from browser I am visiting this URL:

```
http://192.168.0.100/device_status
```

and getting:

```
{"mode":"STANDBY","niveau":3,"hours":1,"minutes":30,"nightmode":1}
```

Also, I have an internal server on my localhost that returns exactly the same JSON, and if I test against this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what you are doing could be setting up a CORS Proxy.

**1.** Install the proxy by typing this command in the terminal:

```
npm install -g corsproxy
```

**2.** Start the proxy with:

```
corsproxy
```

**3.** After starting the proxy you should be able to see where does the proxy runs (check the output in the terminal). Normally it will look like

> http://localhost:9292

**4.** Then you should be able to make requests like:

> http://yourproxy/yourapiendpoint

Comment: I tried this, now I am getting: {"statusCode":502,"error":"Bad Gateway","message":"Parse Error"} ... The proxy is running at: http://HPMB140:1337 and I write: http://HPMB140:1337/192.168.0.242/version in my browser - isn't that write? It all works if I just write: 192.168.0.242/version in the browser.

Comment: Can it be the format that my server is returning in? It just returns raw JSON, without any headers or  anything?